# Unix command to find list of files from a directory which are having more than 500MB

Tags: unix

I am trying to fetch list of list of files which are having more then 500mb in a unix directory.

I used find /path -mtime +180 -size +1G command to do this.
But it is not giving correct details and it shows all the files irrespective of size. Please help me out on this.